# Create Pull Request from develop to main automatically in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, pull-request, azure-pipelines-yaml

In AzureDevOps, we have three branches:

- feature
- develop
- main

We create a Pull Request (PR) from feature to develop. Once the PR is complete, we create a PR from develop to main. Is there a way to create a PR from develop to main automatically when the feature to develop PR is complete?

UPDATE V1:

I added a task in YAML as follows:

```
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
      inputs:
        targetType: filePath
        filePath: ./Scripts/CreatePRBuildTask.ps1
        arguments: '-token $(System.AccessToken)'


-- CreatePRBuildTask.ps1

$user = "PrivateToken"
$branchTarget = "refs/heads/main"
$branchSource = "refs/heads/develop"
$branchTragetPath = $branchTarget -replace "refs/heads/", ""
$teamProject = "team"
$repoName = "$(Build.Repository.Name)"
$organization = "org"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
 
$uriBranchStatus = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$teamProject/_apis/git/repositories/$repoName/stats/branches?name=$branchTragetPath&api-version=5.1"
$uriCheckActivePR = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$teamProject/_apis/git/repositories/$repoName/pullrequests?searchCriteria.targetRefName=$branchTarget&searchCriteria.sourceRefName=$branchSource&api-version=5.1"
$uriCreatePR = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$teamProject/_apis/git/repositories/$repoName/pullrequests?api-version=5.1"

$resultStatus = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriBranchStatus -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

if ($resultStatus.behindCount -eq 0)
{
    Write-Host "Current branch contains last changes from master"
    Return
}

$resultActivePR = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriCheckActivePR -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

if ($resultActivePR.count -gt 0) 
{
    Write-Host "PR exists already"
    Return
}

$bodyCreatePR = "{sourceRefName:'$branchSource',targetRefName:'$branchTarget',title:'Sync changes from $branchSource'}"

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriCreatePR -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body $bodyCreatePR

Write-Host "Created PR" $result.pullRequestId
```

Looks like it is erroring out. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

UPDATE V2:

I see the script running successfully:

[image]

However, I see the log 'PR exists already' log even though there are no active PRs with 'develop' as source branch and 'main' as target branch.

On trying to run this part of script:

```
$bodyCreatePR = "{sourceRefName:'$branchSource',targetRefName:'$branchTarget',title:'Sync changes from $branchSource'}"

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriCreatePR -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body $bodyCreatePR

Write-Host "Created PR" $result.pullRequestId
```

I see:

[image]

no pull request being created. What am I missing?

Here is my YAML file:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: ./Scripts/CreatePRBuildTask.ps1
    arguments: '-token ${{ parameters.token }}'
```

[image]

Comment: I modern world it's time to switch to trunk-based development. You don't need `develop` branch. Just merge to `main`. https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of box, no, we can not. However you can use REST Api. Here is the example of PowerShell inline script: [CreatePRBuildTask.ps1](https://github.com/ashamrai/AzureDevOpsExtensions/blob/master/CustomPSTasks/CreatePRBuildTask.ps1)

Add this step to your develop CI and change:

```
$branchTarget = "$(Build.SourceBranch)"
$branchSource = "refs/heads/master"
$branchTragetPath = $branchTarget -replace "refs/heads/", ""
```

To:

```
$branchTarget = "refs/heads/master"
$branchSource = "refs/heads/develop"
$branchTragetPath = $branchTarget -replace "refs/heads/", ""
```

Additionally, add for project build service permission "Contribute on pull requests" on your repo.

For system access token use the recommendation: [System.AccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken)

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: ./Scripts/CreatePRBuildTask.ps1
    arguments: '-token $(System.AccessToken)'
```

with custom pat:

```
variables:
  CUSTOM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(token)

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: ./Scripts/CreatePRBuildTask.ps1
    arguments: '-token $(CUSTOM_ACCESSTOKEN)'
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you please clarify what this script CreatePRBuildTask.ps1 does? Does it create PR when a build is running or when a PR is complete?

Comment: @user989988 check this [link](https://oshamrai.wordpress.com/2019/12/27/automated-creation-of-git-pull-requests-through-azure-devops-build-pipelines/)

Comment: What should I provide as $user and $token values?

Comment: @user989988 all needed values in the script, you do not need to add additional info. it uses the build service to auth: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken

Comment: Could you please check my 'UPDATE' section in question?

Comment: @user989988 check my updates

Comment: Thank you! Now I see a different unauthorized error - Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
At D:\a\1\s\Scripts\CreatePRBuildTask.ps1:15 char:17
+ ... ultStatus = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriBranchStatus -Method Get -Cont ...

Comment: @user989988 you are using the strange user .... it should be `$user=""`

Comment: that worked ty! I see the script running successfully however I see 'PR exists already' log even though there are no active PRs with 'develop' as source branch and 'main' as target branch. Why is that?

Comment: @user989988 update the last string to see the result:  `Write-Host "Created PR" $result`. Did you assign permissions for build service `Contribute to pull requests`?

Comment: I created PAT however I still see no value in $result. This is what I see- Created PR 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

    
    

<html lang="en-US">
<head><title>
 
            Azure DevOps Services | Sign In

Comment: Please let me know if you have any idea on how to resolve?

Comment: @user989988 `Azure DevOps Services | Sign In` this message says your pat is incorrect to something wrong with authorization. Can you add to the question the resulting yaml and how you store your pat?

Comment: @user989988 can you check my last version? I`ve updated my answer.

Comment: I see this error: Custom.AccessToken : The term 'Custom.AccessToken' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
-token $(Custom.AccessToken)
ObjectNotFound: (Custom.AccessToken:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
CommandNotFoundException

Comment: @user989988 updated. Check how to use custom secrete variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables

Comment: What is the type of this token - string or object?

Comment: @user989988 it is just a string

Comment: Hmm still I see the same Azure DevOps Services | Sign In error. When I tried to print token value, it's empty. so it's not getting passed to the yaml file. :(

Comment: @user989988 I can not find in your ps1 script where you link the token. Your script should start with `param ($token)` line

Comment: Could you please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76077198/is-it-possible-to-cancel-a-azure-devops-pipeline-via-powershell-script